Jupyter Notebook: Unable to Render LaTeX in version 7.0.8
For some unknown reason, I am unable to render LaTeX equations on Jupyter Notebook version 7.0.8. I have changed the cell to Markdown and used the correct notation ($ $ or $$ $$), but nothing is compiled. I am wondering if there is an issue with MathJax, but there seems to be no problem when I use an older version (6.5.4, for example). Is there something I should install? Any ideas? I am using Anaconda and Opera.

That is a rather old version of Jupyter Notebook now. I would suggest trying to make a new conda environment and upgrade it first.

7.0.8 is an old version?

Relatively, in this case. A lot of issues have come up with the roll out of Jupyter Notebook 7+ and so it updates soon. More concerning is I don't even see 7.0.8 as a list in the releases, see here that page three of releases currently shows around that time in the series of release numbering AND THERE IS NO 7.0.8 in the listing, skips from 7.0.6., to 7.10.0. (It is a tag that you can compare to the other versions, but it isn't listed among the 'releases' listing now.) )Maybe it was super flawed and got removed from there?
